# Text search in PostgreSQL: How to order rows by column

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I have a table with people's three desired job positions, ranked from first to third.
The job positions are in a separate table called "job_positions":

```
job_position_id    job_position_title

1                  bar manager
2                  barista
3                  waiter
4                  server
```

The "people" table contains the person_id with the IDs of the job positions they have chosen.

```
person_id    first_position_id   second_position_id   third_position_id

1            1                   2                    3
2            2                   4
```

I want to search this table for a job position and order the results so that the person who has that job in their first_position, will be ranked higher than those who have it in their second or third position.
So in this example, if I search for "barista", I expect the person_id 2 to be displayed first, then person_id 1.

This is my SQL code:

```
  SELECT person_id
  TS_RANK_CD(TO_TSVECTOR('english', a.job_position_title), query_first, 1) AS first,
  TS_RANK_CD(TO_TSVECTOR('english', b.job_position_title), query_second, 1) AS second,
  TS_RANK_CD(TO_TSVECTOR('english', c.job_position_title), query_third, 1) AS third

  FROM people

  LEFT JOIN job_positions a
  ON people.first_position_id = a.job_position_id


  LEFT JOIN PHRASETO_TSQUERY ('barista') AS query_first
  ON TO_TSVECTOR ('english', a.job_position_title) @@ query_first


  LEFT JOIN job_positions b
  ON people.second_position_id = b.job_position_id


  LEFT JOIN PHRASETO_TSQUERY ('barista') AS query_second
  ON TO_TSVECTOR ('english', b.job_position_title) @@ query_second


  LEFT JOIN job_positions c
  ON people.third_position_id = c.job_position_id


  LEFT JOIN PHRASETO_TSQUERY ('barista') AS query_third
  ON TO_TSVECTOR ('english', c.job_position_title) @@ query_third
 
  WHERE (TO_TSVECTOR (a.job_position_title) @@ query_first OR TO_TSVECTOR (b.job_position_title) @@ query_second OR TO_TSVECTOR (c.job_position_title) @@ query_third)
```

The SQL returns the correct matches, but not ranked like they should be. Can I add some kind of score/weight to the columns, to rank them by that score?

Comment: `ORDER BY 2,3,4` ?

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your case with

```
create table job_positions (job_position_id int, job_position_title varchar);
insert into job_positions values (1, 'bar manager');
insert into job_positions values (2, 'barista');
insert into job_positions values (3, 'waiter');
insert into job_positions values (4, 'server');

create table people (person_id int, first_position_id int, second_position_id int, third_position_id int);
insert into people values (1,1,2,3);
insert into people values (2,2,4,NULL);
```

If I understand you correctly you want to order based on the position, if that is true, you can simply solve the problem with the following

```
with unpivoting as (
    select person_id, 1 as position, first_position_id as job_position_id from people UNION ALL
    select person_id, 2 as position, second_position_id as job_position_id from people UNION ALL
    select person_id, 3 as position, third_position_id as job_position_id from people
)
select job_position_title, unpivoting.job_position_id, position, person_id from unpivoting join job_positions on unpivoting.job_position_id = job_positions.job_position_id order by unpivoting.job_position_id, position, person_id;
```

with the expected result

```
 job_position_title | job_position_id | position | person_id
--------------------+-----------------+----------+-----------
 bar manager        |               1 |        1 |         1
 barista            |               2 |        1 |         2
 barista            |               2 |        2 |         1
 waiter             |               3 |        3 |         1
 server             |               4 |        2 |         2
(5 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to unpivot the job preferences for each user.  In fact, you might want to store the data in the unpivoted way -- which is more commonly called *normalized*.

In Postgres, you can use a lateral join to unpivot:

```
select p.*
from people p cross join lateral
     (values (1, p.first_position_id),
             (2, p.second_position_id),
             (3, p.third_position_id)
     ) v(ord, job_position_id) join
     job_positions jp
     using (job_position_id)
where jp.job_position_title = ?
order by v.ord;
```